# Problem with fitting glm.nb : Error in glm.fitter, NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'

Tags: r, regression, glm, poisson, mass

I have problems fitting a glm.nb model.

```
model <- glm.nb(y ~ temp + perc + width + water , data = df)
```

I'm getting the following error.

```
Error in glm.fitter(x = X, y = Y, w = w, etastart = eta, offset = offset, : NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'
```

If I remove any of the predictors the model works fine. The same goes if I exchange one of the predictors for any other data. It seems like it is just this exact combination of predictors that does not work. I've included my full data used in the model in the code below so the problem should be reproducible.

```
data <- read.table( text=
"   width   water   temp    perc    y
95  Ja  10  0   30
210 Ja  10  0   49
150 Ja  18  0   0
240 Ja  16.3    0   1035
80  Ja  16.3    0   0
140 Ja  16.3    0   4
165 Ja  16.3    0   25
140 Ja  16.3    0   1
150 Ja  12.3    0   0
150 Ja  12.3    0   0
80  Ja  12.3    0   0
90  Ja  11.3    0   1
80  Ja  11.3    0   0
77  Nej 11.6    0   0
220 Ja  11.6    0   117
150 Ja  9.9 0   20
130 Ja  11.6    0   0
170 Nej 11.6    0   0
170 Nej 11.6    0   20
120 Ja  10.9    0   0
110 Ja  12.5    0   0
100 Ja  14  0   0
200 Ja  14.8    0   0
120 Nej 14.5    0   0
120 Ja  14.5    0   4
150 Ja  14.5    0   4
170 Nej 17.9    0   1
130 Ja  13.2    0   0
90  Ja  13.2    0   1
110 Ja  13.2    0   1
110 Ja  13.2    0   0
150 Ja  13.2    1.1 0
120 Ja  13.2    1.1 0
130 Ja  13.2    1.1 0
160 Ja  13.2    1.1 0
140 Ja  13.2    1.1 0
190 Ja  8.2 0   0
160 Ja  8.2 0   0
200 Ja  9.3 0   0
100 Ja  9.3 0   0
100 Nej 9.2 0   100
150 Ja  9.2 0   18
100 Ja  10.3    0   6
80  Ja  9.2 0   0
180 Ja  9.2 0   0
180 Nej 11.6    0   0
130 Ja  11.6    0   14
90  Ja  11.6    0   0
130 Ja  10.7    0   4
130 Ja  10.7    0   1
115 Ja  11.6    0   1
180 Ja  11.6    0   0
160 Nej 10.7    0   0
90  Nej 11.6    0   0
125 Ja  12.5    0   0
125 Nej 12.5    0   0
200 Ja  12.5    0   1
110 Nej 12.5    0   4
130 Ja  12.5    0   0
110 Ja  12.5    0   19
130 Nej 12.5    0   1
170 Ja  12.5    0   0
110 Ja  16.2    0   0
130 Ja  16.2    0   0
130 Ja  16.2    0   7
110 Nej 16.2    0   1
110 Nej 16.2    0   11
100 Nej 16.2    0   0
110 Ja  16.2    0   50
120 Ja  16.2    0   0
130 Ja  16.2    0   11
130 Ja  15.7    0   328
190 Ja  15.7    0   130
100 Ja  16.2    0   1
110 Ja  10  0   8
115 Ja  10  0   0
210 Ja  10  0   0
190 Ja  10  0   308
140 Ja  10  0   0
180 Ja  10  0   90
200 Ja  10  0   19
140 Nej 12.5    0   0
130 Ja  12.5    0   0
155 Ja  16.4    0   0
150 Nej 16.4    0   14
160 Ja  16.3    0   0
100 Ja  16.3    0   14
90  Ja  16.3    0   0
95  Ja  16.3    0   0
90  Ja  12.3    0   0
95  Ja  12.3    0   89
90  Ja  12.3    0   1
90  Ja  11.3    0   4
190 Ja  11.3    0   7
200 Nej 8.3 0.3 0
180 Nej 8.3 0.3 14
180 Nej 11.1    0.3 5
200 Nej 11.1    0.3 0
160 Ja  10  0   0
180 Ja  10  0   32
180 Ja  10  0   54
60  Nej 8.3 0.6 0
190 Nej 8.3 0.3 0
192 Nej 8.3 0.3 46
193 Ja  8.3 0.3 0
134 Ja  8.3 0.3 79
133 Ja  8.3 0.3 0
100 Nej 8.3 0.3 2
180 Ja  10.7    0.3 4
180 Ja  9.7 0.3 0
200 Nej 9   0.1 1
100 Ja  9.4 0   0
200 Ja  11.7    0.1 5
180 Ja  11.7    0   0
130 Ja  12.6    0   1
197 Ja  11.7    0   29
180 Ja  9   0   3
150 Ja  9   0   3
95  Ja  9   0   0
90  Ja  9   0   0
180 Ja  9   0   0
160 Ja  11.9    0   1
190 Nej 11.1    0   1
120 Ja  11.2    0   0
80  Ja  11.2    0   0
210 Ja  11.9    0   63
180 Ja  11.9    0   1
120 Ja  11.9    0   1
130 Ja  11.9    0   1
118 Nej 12.8    0   5
140 Ja  12.8    0   0
170 Nej 12.4    0   0
200 Ja  12.4    0   11
120 Ja  12.4    0   0
180 Ja  11.8    0   0
100 Ja  11.8    0   0
100 Ja  12.1    0   0
90  Ja  12.1    0   1
120 Ja  12.1    0   1
370 Ja  10.5    0   3
190 Ja  9.1 0   9
120 Nej 9.1 0   2
130 Ja  11.4    0   0
175 Nej 9.8 0   0
180 Nej 9.8 0   2
190 Ja  9.8 0   14
100 Ja  9.8 0   0
110 Ja  9.8 0   0
160 Ja  11.3    0   8
160 Ja  6.5 0   18
100 Ja  11.3    0   8
120 Ja  11.3    0   45
100 Nej 11.3    0   0
130 Nej 11.3    0   0
120 Ja  11.3    0   0
120 Ja  11.3    0   88
150 Ja  8.2 0   3
176 Nej 8.2 0   5
140 Ja  8.2 0   6
115 Ja  8.2 0   12
300 Ja  10.9    0   39
120 Ja  10.9    0   0
130 Nej 10  0   0
119 Ja  9.8 0   19
100 Ja  16  0   0
155 Nej 12.5    0   0
150 Ja  12.5    0   39
180 Ja  14.8    2.6 0
120 Ja  15.3    0   0
180 Ja  15.3    0   0
110 Ja  14  1.8 0
200 Ja  14  1.8 2
180 Nej 14  1.8 15
180 Ja  15.1    1.8 0
130 Ja  13.6    0   0
120 Ja  13.1    0   10
160 Ja  13.1    0   5
80  Ja  13.6    0   0
130 Ja  14.5    0.8 0
100 Nej 14.5    0.8 0
180 Ja  15  0.8 0
200 Ja  15  0.8 338
160 Ja  15  0.8 0
130 Ja  14.5    0.8 0
190 Nej 14  1.6 4
180 Ja  14  1.6 1
200 Ja  14  1.6 0
200 Ja  14  1.6 70
140 Ja  15.2    0.1 0
140 Ja  15.2    0.1 3
90  Ja  15.2    0.1 0
200 Nej 12.9    2.4 0
160 Ja  13.1    0   1
150 Ja  13.1    0   0
100 Nej 13.1    0   13
100 Ja  13.1    0   0
180 Ja  13.1    0   1
180 Ja  13.1    0   1
180 Ja  11.6    0   0
200 Nej 11.6    0   0
180 Nej 11.6    0   2
100 Ja  12.3    0   0
130 Ja  11.2    0   0
200 Ja  12.4    0.3 0
130 Ja  12.4    0.3 0
100 Ja  10.6    0   2
150 Ja  10.9    0   0
100 Ja  10.9    0   0
180 Ja  10.9    0   42
150 Ja  10.9    0   0
150 Ja  10.9    0   0
200 Nej 10.5    0   0
220 Ja  10.5    0   0
90  Ja  10.5    0   0
110 Ja  10.5    0   1
100 Ja  12  0   0
150 Nej 13  0   0
200 Ja  13  0   0
200 Nej 13  0   0
200 Nej 12.5    0   4
100 Ja  10.6    0   0
150 Ja  10.6    0   8
170 Ja  10.6    0   0
200 Nej 12.5    0   4
200 Ja  12.5    0   11
200 Ja  12.5    0   36
140 Ja  12.5    0   8
140 Ja  12.5    0   0
200 Ja  12.5    0   1
120 Ja  12.5    0   0
100 Nej 14.4    9.1 0
193 Ja  14.4    9.1 24
160 Nej 15.8    4.9 8
130 Ja  15.8    4.9 0
110 Ja  15.8    4.9 0
100 Ja  15.8    9.1 0
140 Ja  15.6    4.9 12
180 Ja  15.6    4.9 19
200 Nej 15.6    4.9 0
190 Ja  15.6    9.1 20
120 Ja  15.8    9.3 0
160 Ja  15.9    9.3 5
120 Ja  15.5    9.3 0
130 Ja  12.4    0   4
90  Nej 12.4    0   0
120 Ja  12.9    0   0
200 Ja  12.9    0   2
90  Nej 12.9    0   0
90  Ja  12.9    0   0
200 Ja  12.4    0   411
140 Ja  12.4    0   0
320 Nej 12.4    0   0
200 Nej 12.4    0   3
140 Ja  14  0   0
200 Ja  15.5    0   3
150 Ja  14.1    0.2 0
90  Ja  13.3    1.1 0
180 Ja  15.5    1.1 0
130 Ja  11.7    0   0
240 Ja  11.7    0   0
200 Nej 14.2    0   0
160 Ja  14.2    0   0
160 Ja  12.9    0   7
100 Ja  14.5    0   0
190 Nej 14.5    0   0
120 Ja  14.5    0   28
110 Ja  14.5    0   0
120 Ja  14.5    0   0
100 Ja  12.9    0   0
210 Nej 12.9    0   36
110 Ja  12.9    0   0
200 Ja  12.9    0   32
100 Ja  12  0   40
180 Nej 12  0   0
190 Ja  12  0   20
140 Ja  10.3    0   0
140 Ja  10.3    0   27
160 Ja  10.3    0   9, header=TRUE )
```

```
model <- glm.nb(y ~ temp + perc + width + water , data = df)
```

```
Error in glm.fitter(x = X, y = Y, w = w, etastart = eta, offset = offset,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'
```

All of my variables are independent from each other.

If I instead use a glm, family= poisson model, it works fine. (except that the model fit is really bad which is why I need to use a negative binomial regression)

l've already read all the pre-existing questions on this topic that I could find, but I still did not manage to figure out what's causing the error or how I can fix it.

Comment: You don't have a variable named `y` in your data.

Comment: Thanks, I must have forgotten to add it to the code I used for the post. I have edited the post now, adding y. The problem is of course the same.